# Python what is the fastest way to make this list tuples into a dict?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of tuples that looks like this;

```
li = [('Replicate 1', '_E748_.txt'),
      ('Replicate 1', '_E749_.txt'),
      ('Replicate 2', '_E758_.txt'),
      ('Replicate 2', '_E759_.txt')]
```

What is the fastest way to create a dict that looks like this;

```
{'Replicate1': ['_E748_.txt', '_E749_.txt'],
 'Replicate2': ['_E758_.txt', '_E759_.txt']}
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

```
>>> li = [('Replicate 1', '_E748_.txt'),
...       ('Replicate 1', '_E749_.txt'),
...       ('Replicate 2', '_E758_.txt'),
...       ('Replicate 2', '_E759_.txt')]
```

Do

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for k, v in li:
...     d.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
...
>>> d
{'Replicate 2': ['_E758_.txt', '_E759_.txt'], 'Replicate 1': ['_E748_.txt', '_E749_.txt']}
```

Or

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d2 = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in li:
...     d2[k].append(v)
...
>>> d2
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'Replicate 2': ['_E758_.txt', '_E759_.txt'], 'Replicate 1': ['_E748_.txt', '_E749_.txt']})
```

Or even the overly fancy

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> get0, get1 = itemgetter(0), itemgetter(1)
>>> dict((key, list(map(get1, subit))) for key, subit in groupby(sorted(li), get0))
{'Replicate 2': ['_E758_.txt', '_E759_.txt'], 'Replicate 1': ['_E748_.txt', '_E749_.txt']}
```

Comment: Thank you! I had no idea that `.setdefault` was a thing. What a nice elegant solution. It makes the loops I wrote look ridiculous.

Comment: @JamesDraper:  If `.setdefault()` didn't exist you would do something like `if k not in d:d[k] = [v]` `else: d[k].append(v)`.